# attempting to put dynamic input data in a variable via cat method

Tags: shell, shell-script, cat

I'm attempting to write a bash script that should be able to collect data from ttyS0 and put in a variable.

I need to talk with a device on the serial line, that is a module able to receive AT commands that I can send with echo > ttyS0 and capture the related answer in a variable. 
It's possible to do this without store the received answer in a variable  (i.e.
cat /dev/ttyS0 & ), but if I try to put this data in a variable (i.e. VAR=$(cat /dev/ttyS0 &) it doesn't work (in VAR I can not find anything after the answer of the module).

What I'm able to do "by hand" via gnome terminals (I'm working with a Ubuntu distribution) is the following:

1. From a GNOME terminal that I call (A), I run (as root)

   ```
   # VAR=$(cat /dev/ttyS0)
   ```

   This command doesn't return the root prompt `#`, because probably `cat /dev/ttyS0` is running and waiting for input.
2. From another GNOME terminal that I call (B), I run

   ```
   # echo -en "hello in VAR\r" > /dev/ttyS0
   ```

   The `hello in VAR` string should go to `/dev/ttyS0` and put by cat in `VAR`
3. Then from (B):

   ```
   # killall cat
   ```

   From GNOME terminal (A) I can see that the prompt (`#`) returns;
4. Finally from GNOME terminal (A):

   ```
   # echo "$VAR"
   ```

   and I receive the `hello in VAR` string.

I tried to implement this via bash script in this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

killall cat

BASHTESTS_DIR=/root/Desktop/Tips_tricks_tutorials/bash_scripting
cd $BASHTESTS_DIR

echo "before VARcat_dev_ttyS0"
VAR=$(cat /dev/ttyS0)
echo "after VARcat_dev_ttyS0"
echo -en "hello in VAR\r" > /dev/ttyS0 
sleep 2
killall cat 
echo "content of VAR: $VAR"

exit 0
```

but the script stops after `echo "before VARcat_dev_ttyS0"`
How can I implement what I want or what I'm able to do with two GNOME terminals?

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101). What is your final objective here?

Comment: Please update your question to mention that you really are wanting to talk with a device on the serial line. This is important as it invalidates your stated assumptions and example working. Please also restate your requirements: are you wanting to talk to your serial device from your terminals, or create a testbed for some other undescribed program which doesn't require the serial device to be connected?

Comment: I roiama I did it. please see the new introduction of my requirement

Answer (score 3):

It appears you're trying to use `ttyS0` as a means to connect two processes. This won't work reliably since `ttyS0` is the interface to a serial line (`COM1:` in Windows-speak).

On the other hand, it might be that information is missing from your question. If you really do have a device on your serial port, please make that clear.

What I believe you're looking for is a pipe. In the filesystem this looks much like a file, but allows data written to one side to be read from another. It's what is behind the scenes of the ubiquitous `|` operator, as in e.g. `id | nl`.

You can create a pipe with the `mkfifo` command, or `mknod p` if you insist.

Terminal #1

```
mkfifo /tmp/pipe        # Create the pipe
ls -l /tmp/pipe         # Notice the first character is 'p'

echo hello > /tmp/pipe  # Write to it
rm -f /tmp/pipe         # Remove the pipe
```

Terminal #2

```
cat /tmp/pipe           # Read from the other side of the pipe
```

You can extend the Terminal #2 code like this. Remember, though, that for each new read (actually open/read/close) on the pipe you need to give it fresh data.

```
read VAR </tmp/pipe    # Read one line from the pipe
VAR=(cat /tmp/pipe)    # Read from the pipe until EOF
```

Comment: In case of a single script, a background (e.g. `&`)  is needed for the line that read/write the pipe (which ever you code first). This is not needed in case of two terminal.

Comment: @roaima an terdon:  I need ttyS0, because spots of data are coming to this port and I need to put them in a variable . however I'll try roaima suggestions